# How to select subprojects to package at runtime (with ScopeFilter)?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am writing a task to package several but not all subprojects together, and am using a setting for exclusion and `task.all(scope filter)` to select projects. However sbt keeps say `References undefined settings at runtime`.

Here is **project/build.scala** I use followed by the error I need your advice on:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object build extends Build {
  lazy val root = Project(
    id = "root",
    base = file("."),
    aggregate = Seq(a,b),
    settings = Seq(
      exclude := Seq(a),
      module := moduleImpl.value,
      modules := modulesImpl.value
    )
  )

  lazy val a = Project(
    id = "a",
    base = file("a")
  )

  lazy val b = Project(
    id = "b",
    base = file("b")
  )

  val exclude = settingKey[Seq[ProjectReference]]("excludes")
  val module = taskKey[String]("module")
  val modules = taskKey[Seq[String]]("modules")

  def moduleImpl = Def.task {
      projectID.value.organization
  }

  def modulesImpl = Def.taskDyn {
    module.all(ScopeFilter(inAggregates(ThisProject) -- inProjects(exclude.value: _*)))
  }
}
```

This is the error that I really want to get rid of:

```
> show modules
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last root/*:modules for the full output.
[error] (root/*:modules) sbt.Init$RuntimeUndefined: References to undefined settings at runtime.
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed 2014-06-12 16:48:05
```

Any idea to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sbt complains, because the task you're using is not defined in the sub-projects.

The solution would be not to call it on `module`, but on `moduleImpl`

```
lazy val moduleImpl = Def.task {
  projectID.value.organization
}

def modulesImpl = Def.taskDyn {
  moduleImpl.all(ScopeFilter(inAggregates(ThisProject) -- inProjects(exclude.value: _*)))
}
```

PS. When you do

```
Project(
  id = "root",
  base = file("."),
  aggregate = Seq(a,b),
  settings = Seq(
    exclude := Seq(a),
    module := moduleImpl.value,
    modules := modulesImpl.value
  )
)
```

You override all the default settings. You may want to add them with `Defaults.defaultSettings` or use `settings` method on the `Project`.